# Decimation Aliasing

Tags: aliasing, decimation

Lets say you have a signal which is sampled at rate $f_s$ and the bandwidth after sampling is $B$.

Now you want to decimate this signal with a new sample rate $f_{s, new}$ where $f_{s, new} < f_s$ and you also are only interested in preserving bandwidth $B'$ where $B' < B$. Also $f_{s, new}$ > $2B$' and $f_{s, new}$ < $B'$

Is there a way to calculate the band of frequencies that will be aliased to the band of interest i.e. from $-B'$ to $B'$

Comment: Do you think you could clarify this a little? Anything above $\frac{Fs_{new}}{2}$ will be aliased. Therefore, if $B' > \frac{Fs_{new}}{2}$, then the band of interest will be aliased. But is this really what your question is about?